# Can Query Store Show Spills To Tempdb?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, tempdb, query-store

I know that Query Store can show tempdb usage as of SQL Server 2017, but can it show spills to tempdb? I'm highly confident that the plan cache can.

Comment: why are you confident?

Comment: @nbk sp_blitzcache reports on it.

Comment: sys.dm_exec_query_stats  contains spill stats SQL Server 2017 CU3 +  : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-query-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: If it was going to store that aggregated information it would be in `sys.query_store_runtime_stats` - and no such columns there - so looks like not persisted to query store

Comment: @MitchWheat That's helpful, but I'm pretty sure that's got nothing to do with Query Store.

Comment: It hasn't. why do you care where the info comes from? AFAIK it is not available from QS currently.

Comment: @MitchWheat Because Query Store contains far more long-lasting information than the plan cache.

Comment: FWIW, `sp_blitzcache` also (in your own words) "*has nothing to do with query store*". If you're satisfied with it, then you should be equally satisfied with what Mitch presented you.

Comment: @J.Mini : usually when one is looking at TempDb spills, its related about something that is happening now or very recently, not a month ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### nope

But you may be able to infer that a *select* spilled to disk if values for average or total writes are "high", and the query plan:

- Doesn't contain any spooling operators
- Does contain operators which may spill (sort, hash, etc.)

See [Why would a SELECT query cause writes?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/191825/32281) for more details.

If you're on SQL Server 2017+, [sys.query_store_runtime_stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-query-store-runtime-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) has columns for tempdb space used, but this is not specific to spills.

> number of pages used in tempdb for the query plan within the
> aggregation interval (expressed as a number of 8-KB pages).

They have the standard min, max, last, etc. prefixes appended to *_tempdb_space_used*.